# Anchoring/docking behavior in WPF on Canvas layout

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am arranging quite freely a lot of elements on a Canvas layout, in fact the elements represent an interactive flow-chart. As transformations are applied, I need relative transformations on some of the elements.

Especially I require some elements being anchored or docked to their parent elements. I found different solutions, however I don't know if they solve my problem in the most elegant way.

Here is an example:

```
<Line X1="80" X2="800" Y1="730" Y2="730"/>
<Polygon Points="0,30 40,0 40,60" Canvas.Left="48" Canvas.Top="700"/>
```

The Polygon draws a triangle and I would like to let it dock on the left side of line. Which means, when translating the line to a new position or when scaling it down, the Polygon should move with it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put them in a canvas of their own, that way you can position the outer canvas absolutely and keep the inner stuff together.

like this:

```
<Canvas>
    <Line X1="60" X2="820" Y1="60" Y2="760"> <!--some other line--> </Line>
    <Canvas Canvas.Left="48" Canvas.Top="700">
        <Polygon Points="0,30 40,0 40,60"/>
        <Line X1="32" X2="752" Y1="30" Y2="30"/>
    </Canvas>        
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Put the lines into their own canvas? I could also let them start on X1=0 and position them with Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top. Sorry, this does not answer my question, maybe I was to unprecise? I would like to know how to position elements dynamically by using the absolute position.

Comment: please see my update, maybe I wasn't clear enough. If you want to keep elements together simply put them in a container that keeps them together and transform the container instead

Comment: @Markus-hutter Thanks, this solves it partially, because how can I scale down the line inside, and only the line, and let the polygon translate to the new position of the line?

Comment: Just try it out, when applying scale down effect on the canvas the magic is done by itself.